# Divisors and higher cohomologies

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles

Given a divisor $D$ on a smooth, complex manifold there is an associated holomorphic line bundle $\mathcal{O}(D)$. The space of holomorphic sections $H^0(\mathcal{O}(D))$ is directly related to the complete linear system $|D|$ of the divisor,
$$
|D| = \mathbb{P}\big(H^0(\mathcal{O}(D))\big) \,.
$$
Given this relation, it seems natural to ask: is there also a relatively simple relation between the higher cohomologies $H^{i>0}(\mathcal{O}(D))$ and objects determined by the divisor $D$?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking since for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ we have that $\Gamma(\mathcal{F})=H^0(\mathcal{F})$ by definition. Can you clarify what sort of answer you're looking for?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for your question. I didn't notice the ambiguity; I have updated the wording to better capture what I mean.

Comment: This https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38966/what-is-sheaf-cohomology-intuitively/ might be useful to you.